# Identifier not found when im calling a function?

Tags: c++, function, declaration, definition

So I'm making a math game, but when I try to call a function in a function as you can see in my code, it says **'Start':Identifier not found**, Even tho I put the function above the function that I'm trying to call but it still saying identifier not found, any help?

```cpp
void Inventory()
    {
        char inv;
        cout << "Do you wan't to open your inventory?" << endl;
        cout << "1.Yes 2.No." << endl;
        cin >> inv;
        switch (inv) {
        case '1':
            cout << "You opened your inventory" << endl;
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "Returning to main menu" << endl;
            Sleep(1000);
            Start();
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

and here is the function im calling.

````cpp
void Start()
    {
        points = 10;
        system("color b");
        cout << R"(
             __  __          _____ _   _   __  __ ______ _   _ _    _ 
            |  \/  |   /\   |_   _| \ | | |  \/  |  ____| \ | | |  | |
            | \  / |  /  \    | | |  \| | | \  / | |__  |  \| | |  | |
            | |\/| | / /\ \   | | | . ` | | |\/| |  __| | . ` | |  | |
            | |  | |/ ____ \ _| |_| |\  | | |  | | |____| |\  | |__| |
            |_|  |_/_/    \_\_____|_| \_| |_|  |_|______|_| \_|\____/ 

                                      PLEASE SELECT AN OPTION!

    )";
        system("color b");
        int shop;
        int shopitems;
        char inventory;

        cout << "   You have " << points << " points!" << endl;
        cout << "   [1] Play" << endl;
        cout << "   [2] Inventory" << endl;
        cout << "   [3] Shop" << endl;
        cout << "   [4] Exit" << endl;
        printf("   >> ");
        cin >> inventory;

        switch (inventory) {
            case '1':
                PlayGame();
                break;
            case '2':
                Inventory();
                break;
            case '3':
                printf("3");
                break;
            case '4':
                printf("4");
                break;
                return;
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Most likely you need *forward declarations* for `Start` and `Inventory` - then you can order the code however you like.

Comment: Is Start declared before Inventory in the code? At least a function declaration should be present, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration

Comment: Why are you calling `Start` from `Inventory` and vice versa? This isn't going to end welll

Comment: you probably want a loop in `Start` and then in `Invetory` you dont call `Start` again, but simply return back to `Start`. The way you wrote is isnt very stack-friendly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first declare the functions

```
void Inventory();
void Start();
```

and after that define them.

Comment: define them? how?

Comment: The function bodies you posted in the question are the function definitions.

Comment: @dan1247 You already defined them. Only place the additional declarations beffore the function definitions.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I am not sure why you are using case when it's an if/else situation.  Then you don't need a break - it automatically returns to the start.  As for the functions, you can either declare the functions before your `main` function or you can create function prototypes before main, and then call the functions after (my personal preference).  I like to start tracing my code in main, so prefer the prototypes before main, the functions after.

You may want to look here for more information:  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ or use a C++ playlist on building a game to also learn the language constructs.

Comment: i use the switch because its easier and shorter than using if/else statement , but thanks for advices and i also want the code look simple

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about undefined identifier. If the OP is interested in if/switch differences, he/she will ask about it.